# Changing parameters for GCP CLoud run with gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, gcloud

When we change `labels` for existing `CLoud Run serivces` using `gcloud` command , it does a `deployment` as well as `revision` change

```
      $gcloud run services update test --update-labels env=prod,test=test1
      ✓ Deploying... Done.                                         
      ✓ Creating Revision...
      ✓ Routing traffic...
      Done.
      Service [test1] revision [test1-00003-wik] has been deployed and is serving 100 percent of traffic at https://test1-ukliefksia-uc.a.run.app
```

Does it cause downtime during label only change without any code change ? It seems traffic is routed and so no downtime for application . Please confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#revision) any change would result in a new version, this means that every change wheather the container was modied or not will result in a new version.

How the version Updates are made is that the new container is deployed and once it is deployed the traffic is routed. **Therefore there is no downtime in any redeployment.**

Comment: Does that also mean a new image is pushed to container repo automatically with me version no for any service change?

Comment: yes, it means that